# How to allow special characters like open & closed brackets "(",")" at text box search when using regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to highlight the search string (including special characters) in `Infragistics UltraWebGrid`.
Search string is highlighted, but when I search special characters like `(",")` that shows below error

> parsing "(" - not enough )'s

error shows on search button clicked

kindly suggest for above error.

Note: other special characters are working fine like `-,/,@`.. etc..

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a \ to special chars

(\.\,\")

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses and certain other characters used to define a what you are searching for must be prepended with `\`.

Example:

This will throw the exception: `ArgumentException: parsing "Some thing (?)" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.`

```
var result2 = Regex.Match ("Some thing (?)", @"Some thing (?)").Success;
```

...So you need to do this, which will return true:

```
var result1 = Regex.Match ("Some thing (?)", @"Some thing \(\?\)").Success;
```

In your search, you will need to escape chars that way. [Here's a quick reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#character_escapes).